# Create 2 FrameLayouts below each other

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem... I want to create 2 FrameLayouts below each other, so I tried this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#071c3f">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the first FrameLayout gets shown, but the second FrameLayout is not visible on the screen.
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of `android:orientation` is **horizontal**. So if you set the `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, you won't see the second `FrameLayout` in horizontal.

> I want to create 2 FrameLayouts below each other

Add the `android:orientation="vertical"` would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#374233"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        >   

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```